# Rolling shutter time per row on downsampled images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

When working with rolling shutter images, it is common that we want to know the timestamp of each row (for example for motion interpolation). Using $T$ as frame timestamp (mid-exposure, mid-row) $T_i$ as the timestamp of the mid-exposure of row $i$, $n_{rows}$ the total number of rows in the image, and $t_{line}$ the readout time of a single line, the formula used is usually:

$T_i = (i - 0.5\cdot n_{rows})\cdot t_{line}$

Now, my question is: what happens if we downsample the image by a factor, let's say, of 2? In other words, halving the resolution of the image. My guess is that it depends on the downsampling strategy:

- **Taking only even(odd) rows and cols**: In this case I assume one would just use the timing corresponding to the original rows.
- **2x2 block mean**: In this case, I would do: $T_j = (T_i + T_{i+1})/2$. That is, the new time for the output row $j$ would be the mean of the two corresponding rows on the input image. However, I am not sure if this approximation is valid for things like motion interpolation.

I couldn't find similar discussions out there, so I would like to hear how you would approach this.

Thank you!